# Set bootstrap col-md-3 divs to the same height

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On a bootstrap webshop template, im listing the items into col-md-3 divs.
How can i set these divs to the same height?

If the item name is to short or long, or of the price, only the normal price is displayed, each div height is smaller, and they arent in line.

[image: You can see the problem on the uploaded image]

Is there any jquery  plugin for this problem? Or css? And i only want this, if the users device is not mobile.

Comment: seems like a duplicate question. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna use the heighter one get the max height and use for all the box.

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$(yourelemselector).each(function(){
   var thisH = $(this).height();
   if (thisH > maxHeight) { maxHeight = thisH; }
});

$(yourelemselector).height(maxHeight);
```

EDIT

If work why you don't accept the answer ? Second u can't use the same post for different question, by the way what you ask about 'how put i top input group' is not clear